# word 2019 show source comments and medium

Tags: microsoft-word, bibliography, citations, microsoft-word-2019

I'm trying to show some of the extra fields that you can enter when creating a source in word 2019.

This is how the bibliography looks together with an in-text citation:

[image: bibliograhy in word 2019]

The thing is, I've added a comment and the medium of the source like so:

[image: Edit source dialog in word 2019]

I'd like to see the medium and comment field added to my bibliography if the fields aren't empty, I have been trying to figure this out for a while, but I haven't been able to find any kind of option or what not in word to achieve this.

How can I best achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into creating a custom bibliography:  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/word/concepts/objects-properties-methods/create-custom-bibliography-styles